# How to figure out REST API route of Comala document management for Confluence Cloud using Forge?

Tags: api, rest, confluence, confluence-forge

I started using Atlassian Forge to circumvent disabled user macro support for Confluence Cloud. I set out to implement a function that utilizes Comala's REST API according to:

https://comalatech.bitbucket.io/comala-workflows/6.16.0/restapi/index.html

this should be something like:
`/wiki/rest/api/content/${contentId}/status`

or

`/content/{contentId}/status/`

In the following context of Forge:

```
const fetchComalaData = async (contentId) => {
  const res = await api
    .asApp()
    .requestConfluence(route`/wiki/rest/api/content/${contentId}/status`, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    });

  const data = await res.json();

  return data;
};
```

While I have no issue to access the default REST API by Confluence, I cannot access the Comala API.

`{ code: 401, message: 'Unauthorized; scope does not match' }`

**How do I figure out the correct route?** It should be similar for all cloud instances of Comala.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no API support for Comala Document Management in the Cloud:

[image: No API Support for Comala Cloud]